# the behavior of include

Tags: php, xampp, filenames

This might be a dumb and simple question, but couldn't find any related research from google nor I have experienced before...To replicate the scenario, I have simplify the original structure and set up an environment like the following:

File Structure:

```
ROOT
 |---/config/config.php
 |---/system/system.php
 index.php
```

In `config/system.php`

```
return array (
    "test" => "this is test"
);
```

In `config/config.php`

```
class config
{
    public static function site ()
    {
        return include "system.php";
    }
}
```

In `index.php`

```
include "config/config.php";
$result = config::site();

var_dump($result);
```

I was expecting `$result` will contain the array from `system.php`, but it actually output: `int(1)`

I am guessing it has successfully included the file, that's why it output `1`, but thats only my guessing...

If I change the filename from

`/config/system.php` to `/config/sys.php`

and in `/config/config.php`, change this statement from

`return include "system.php";` to `return include "sys.php";`

it will output my desired result:

```
array(1) { ["test"]=> string(12) "this is test" }
```

Although I found a workaround, but I don't understand why the filename is matter as I don't think this is in the case of php reserved words. Furthermore, I tried naming the file to `echo.php` or `strpos.php` and it still working as expected.

Why can't I name my script as `system.php` ??

If its matter, my workstation is using xampp under: Windows 64bit, php 5.6.8

Comment: you are getting the correct output. From PHP manual `include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1. `

Comment: @bansi See: http://php.net/manual/de/function.return.php

Comment: Until now can't reproduce the problem with PHP 5.5.9-1 Ubuntu.

Comment: Not strictly related to your question, it's a good idea to append the `__DIR__` magic constant before include paths to prevent the changes in the execution dir (for example if the script is called by cron) from breaking the includes.

Comment: @bansi I totally agree with you, but shouldn't it also return me the array ??

Comment: @Rizier123 Maybe also is a problem from xampp ?? hmm, I will look into it. thanks

Comment: cannot test it now no comp near me. but the actual behavior should be return 1 on successful include. May be i need to look into the code and amend the manual

Comment: @Andrew Got it reproduced: With PHP 5.6.3 32bit (XAMPP)

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks for trying it out :), I was starting to think the problem only happen to me

Comment: ah then the problem is in 5.6.x then this really needs a code checking to see how it is in 7.x

Comment: @Tuure actually, you are right. it has something to do with the path. In the original, I have defined an absolute path but I just realized I only used in an autoload function and not within the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deserved a downvote for an obvious problem; a classic RTM **"carefully"**. I cannot emphasize more of how dumb I am....... My original structure has defined an absolute path but only used in the autoload function and not inside that class.

From the [PHP: include - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given,
>   the include_path specified. **If the file isn't found in the
>   include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own
>   directory and the current working directory before failing.**

So I checked the include_path and was actually pointing to `.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR`, and under it, you guess it right, a file named `system.php`.

My `include` found the right file, but not the file that I was expecting. It was actually including a pear extension file instead of my intended script.

I didn't know or remember that I have pear extension installed when I installed XAMPP, nor I know XAMPP pointed it to pear folder as a default setting.

In conclusion, I need to either set the `set_include_path()` to point to the current project folder or explicitly call it with an absolute path

Sorry for wasting your time